# How to perform git diff commit-id <three dots> working

Tags: git

I will refer to the different changes working, cached or committed. From what I know,

```
git diff              ->   git diff HEAD..<working>
git diff <commit>     ->   git diff <commit>..<working>
```

I want to see the incremental changes in my working branch (ie even the uncommitted changes not present in HEAD) which came after some commit. So what I want is something like,

```
?                     ->   git diff <commit>...<working>
```

Is there a way for this?

Comment: What does "the incremental changes" mean? Are you saying you want multiple diffs, one for each commit along the way?

Comment: I can't phrase it right. I meant what "diff triple-dot" is supposed to do.

Comment: So the question is what to do about the fact that the work tree is not a thing that you can put at the right side of `...` in a diff? I don't get it, because `...` is about comparing branch tips from their split point. What is it you want to do that `git diff <commit>` does not do?

Comment: From git-scm,
`git diff [<options>] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>…​]   
    This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second <commit>, starting at a common ancestor of both <commit>.`   
I am searching for a way to "view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second <commit> *+ the uncommitted changes*"
`git diff <commit>` will also show the changes that are not in my branch from split-point

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is a log::

```
git log --patch some-commit HEAD
```

That leaves out the stuff you have hanging around on your working tree.

Comment: I don't want to leave out the *working* changes, that's what I am asking.